Why is the onClose Button Not Working on My Subscription Banner?
I'm creating a promotional banner for my customers to encourage subscription purchases. This banner includes a button at the top intended to close the banner. Despite multiple attempts and various methods, I am unable to get the button to function correctly. Could you provide assistance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:social_rise/src/blocs/home/home_bloc.dart';
import 'package:social_rise/src/blocs/home/home_state.dart';
import 'package:social_rise/src/constants/appcolor.dart';
import 'package:social_rise/src/presentation/widgets/buttons/ksubscription_button.dart';

class InsightScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const InsightScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // TODO: implement listener
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: AppColor.backgroundColor,
          body: Column(
            children: [
              SubscriptionButton(
                onClose: () {
                  log("Clossed Button Pressed");
               
                },
                onPremium: () {
                    log("hey");
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:responsive_sizer/responsive_sizer.dart';
import 'package:social_rise/src/presentation/widgets/misc/gradient_text.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

class SubscriptionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function()? onPremium;
  final void Function() onClose;

  const SubscriptionButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPremium,
    required this.onClose,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.h, bottom: 1.h),
      height: 14.875.h,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        gradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [
          Color(0xff4188FF),
          Color(0xffFFC555),
        ]),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 10,
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 1.h),
                const Text(
                  "Maximize your impact with Premium",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
                const Text(
                  "3x Engagement / Unlimited Posts / Content Repurposing",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 1.h),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                      onPremium!();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 4.7.h,
                    width: 80.25.w,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: GradientText(
                        "Get Premium",
                        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                          Color(0xff4188FF),
                          Color(0xffFFC555),
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 5,
            top: 5,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
  
                onClose();
              },
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
               
                child:  Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}




I have checked your code , onclose button is perfectly fine, there is nothing wrong with that

not working on iOS emulator.
